# how to add array values in text box

Tags: javascript, arrays, codeigniter-2

I have three text box that given as an array, I want to add two text box and get a result in the third text box as shown in below.

```
<tbody>
   <?php 
     $i=1;
     foreach ($sub as $row) 
     {
   ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $i++;?>
</td>
<td>  <div><span style="border: none;"><input type="text" name="subject[]" class="textbox" value="<?php echo $row->subject_name;?>"></span></div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="mark-1[]" value="" id="mark1"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="mark-2[]" value="" id="mark2"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="total-mark[]" value="" id="totmark"  onclick="add_number()"></td>
</tr>
<?php  }  ?>
<tr>
<th colspan="4">Total Mark</th>
<td></td></tr>
</tbody>
```

i have used the below script and its running but getting a result in the first loop

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function add_number() {
var first_number = parseInt(document.getElementById("mark1").value);
var second_number = parseInt(document.getElementById("mark2").value);
var result = first_number + second_number;
document.getElementById("totmark").value = result;
 }
</script>
```

please help us get an answer

Comment: as you are inside a loop using `id` is not an ideal way. Try using `class` instead and access a particular `class` element using `this` keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html

```
<tbody>
   <?php 
     $i=1;
$k=1;
     foreach ($sub as $row) 
     { $k++;
   ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $i++;?>
</td>
<td>  <div><span style="border: none;"><input type="text" name="subject[]" class="textbox" value="<?php echo $row->subject_name;?>"></span></div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="mark-1[]" value="" id="mark1-<?php echo $k;?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="mark-2[]" value="" id="mark2-<?php echo $k;?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="total-mark[]" value="" id="totmark-<?php echo $k;?>"  onclick="add_number(<?php echo $k;?>)"></td>
</tr>
<?php  }  ?>
<tr>
<th colspan="4">Total Mark</th>
<td></td></tr>
</tbody>
```

Script

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
function add_number(k) {
var first_number = parseInt(document.getElementById("mark1-"+k).value);
var second_number = parseInt(document.getElementById("mark2-"+k).value);
var result = first_number + second_number;
document.getElementById("totmark-"+k).value = result;
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the repeated IDs for each iteration, mark1, mar2, mark1, mark2, and so on.  The function `getElementById` is returning the first element.

An alternative is to use the function `closest('tr')` and then find by name `[name="mark-1[]"]` and `[name="mark-2[]"]`.  Then find the field to store the result using this `.querySelector('[name="total-mark[]"]')`.

Finally, using the function `addEventListener` you can bind the event click to the whole set of elements `[name="total-mark[]"]`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[name="total-mark[]"]').forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', add_number);
});

function add_number() {
  var tr = this.closest('tr');
  
  var first_number = tr.querySelector('[name="mark-1[]"]').value;
  var second_number = tr.querySelector('[name="mark-2[]"]').value;
  var result = Number(first_number) + Number(second_number);
  
  this.value = result;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="mark-1[]" value="" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="mark-2[]" value="" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="total-mark[]" value=""  placeholder='click to totalize'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="mark-1[]" value="" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="mark-2[]" value="" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="total-mark[]" value=""  placeholder='click to totalize'></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

A recommendation is using the current index from the PHP variable `$i` and add specific IDs to every field, that way you will be able to get the elements directly.  For example, the two fields would have these IDs: `mark-1-1[]`, `mark-1-2[]` and `mark-2-1[]`, `mark-2-2[]`, and so on.

This approach uses the attribute `dataset`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[name="total-mark[]"]').forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', add_number);
});

function add_number() {
  var field = this.dataset.field;
  
  var first_number = document.getElementById('mark-1-' + field + '[]').value;
  var second_number = document.getElementById('mark-2-' + field + '[]').value;
  
  var result = Number(first_number) + Number(second_number);
  this.value = result;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="mark-1-1[]" value="" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="mark-2-1[]" value="" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" data-field='1' name="total-mark[]" value=""  placeholder='click to totalize'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="mark-1-2[]" value="" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="mark-2-2[]" value="" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" data-field='2' name="total-mark[]" value=""  placeholder='click to totalize'></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```